# Opportunity custom button to open different links not filling URL with merge information

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a custom button that opens different links depending on if my custom field is blank.

The formula works for parsing the IF statement, but my issue now is that the merge fields don't fill the information, they display as "{!CASESAFEID(Opportunity.Id)}" and "{!Opportunity.Lookup_Quote_ID__c}" respectively when the page loads.

How do I get the field information to merge into the URL?

Formula:

```
{! IF(ISBLANK(Opportunity.ChannelOnline_Quote_ID__c) , 
      URLFOR("https://support.oetc.org/hc/en-us/requests/new?email={!CASESAFEID(Opportunity.Id)}"),
      URLFOR("https://support.oetc.org/hc/en-us/requests/new?email={!Opportunity.Lookup_Quote_ID__c}"))}
```

These are test URLs but the real ones I want to insert the value in the middle of the URL rather than just at the end, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Rather than having the values as part of the URL, I had to concatenate them as seen below:

```
{! IF(ISBLANK(Opportunity.ChannelOnline_Quote_ID__c) , 
  URLFOR("...?email=" &CASESAFEID(Opportunity.Id)&),
  URLFOR("...?email=" &Opportunity.Lookup_Quote_ID__c&))}
```

This article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_and_concatenate.htm&type=5 was helpful.